# deploying fedena project on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, fedena

I had setup rails [Fedena](http://projectfedena.org/) on my local machine but cannot make it happen on `heroku`.

Fedena does not have `Gemfile` and `heroku` is giving error due to this.

After adding `sudo Gemfile` with some gems, heroku accepts the project but after that it started giving errors for gems (Install this, that)...

The plugins command is also not working on heroku.

Kindly help, if anyone have idea about this...

Comment: did you find a solution for this?